# Passport Js documentation Custom Callback syntax

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js

I am using passport.js for my node app. In the Custom Callback section I found the following code(lets say it Code A):

```
app.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
    if (err) { return next(err); }
    if (!user) { return res.redirect('/login'); }
    req.logIn(user, function(err) {
      if (err) { return next(err); }
      return res.redirect('/users/' + user.username);
    });
  })(req, res, next);
});
```

My question is I am not able to understand passing (req, res, next) at the end. How the following code(lets say it Code B):

```
app.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
    if (err) { return next(err); }
    if (!user) { return res.redirect('/login'); }
    req.logIn(user, function(err) {
      if (err) { return next(err); }
      return res.redirect('/users/' + user.username);
    });
  });
});
```

How Code B is different from Code A ?

If I simplify Code A then it will be like :

```
app.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('local', function(..){..})(req, res, next);
});
```

Further 
passport.authenticate(..)(req, res, next);
which means expression like
function(..)(req,res, next) 
My Question is more about understanding the syntax 
function(..)(parameters)

Answer (score 0):

`authenticate()` function is structured like this:

```
module.exports = function authenticate(passport, name, options, callback) {
  // ...
  return function authenticate(req, res, next) {
      // ...
      strategy.success = function(user, info) {
        if (callback) {
          return callback(null, user, info);
        }
      }
     // ...
  })
};
```

So it takes two series of parameters:

- The first one (in your case `'local'` and the callback function) is used to tell passport to authenticate you, and how to do it;
- The second handles the function to control your app with `req`, `res` and `next` parameters.

Hope it helps you to understand!

Comment: Thanks !! . Yes, now I am able to understand